# Access Database SELECTION with VB.NET code

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, command

I have a table with 2 field 'Medico' and 'Listino' so I want to select only the fields Listino where there's 'Medico' = Medhi

```
MEDICO        LISTINO
---------------------
Medhi         Gheller
Ashi          Cadon
Pamdo         Gheller


result:
Gheller
```

Because Medhi has the 'Listino' Gheller

Here's the code

```
    Public DBPath As String = "Listini.accdb"
    Public StringaConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= " & DBPath & ""
    Public DBConn As New OleDbConnection(StringaConn)

    Dim Medico As String = "Medhi"
    DBConn.Open()
    Dim DBCommAssociazione As OleDbCommand = DBConn.CreateCommand
    DBCommAssociazione.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    DBCommAssociazione.CommandText = "SELECT Listino FROM Associazioni WHERE Medico=Medhi"

    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
    reader = DBCommAssociazione.ExecuteReader

    While reader.Read()
        Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(reader(0))
        Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(reader(1))

    End While

    DBConn.Close()
```

Thank you.

Comment: Medico is a text field. To search on this column for a constant value you need to put single quotes around the constant value 'Mehdi'

Answer (score 1):

You are missing cotes `''` in query `WHERE Medico='Medhi'`, but i advice you to use the Parameter to avoid SQL injections , like this :

```
Dim Medico As String = "Medhi"
DBConn.Open()
Dim DBCommAssociazione As OleDbCommand = DBConn.CreateCommand
DBCommAssociazione.CommandType = CommandType.Text
DBCommAssociazione.CommandText = "SELECT Listino FROM Associazioni WHERE Medico=@Medico"
DBCommAssociazione.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Medico", Medico)

Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
reader = DBCommAssociazione.ExecuteReader

While reader.Read()
    Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(reader(0))
End While
```

Answer (score 0):

Medico is a text field. To search values on this columns you should put constant values between single quotes. But in a more realistic scenario, you search for a particular Medico following the input of your user.

So you should use a code like the following

```
Public DBPath As String = "Listini.accdb"
Public StringaConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= " & DBPath & ""

Using DBConn = New OleDbConnection(StringaConn)
Using DBCommAssociazione = DBConn.CreateCommand
    DBConn.Open()
    Dim Medico = WhateverMethodYouHaveToReturnAMedicoFromUserInput()
    DBCommAssociazione.CommandText = "SELECT Listino FROM Associazioni WHERE Medico=@medico"

    DBCommAssociazione.Parameters.Add("@medico", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = Medico
    Using reader = DBCommAssociazione.ExecuteReader
       While reader.Read()
          Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(reader(0))
        End While
    End Using
End Using
```

Notice also that the query returns just one field. In your While loop you try to read two fields (reader(0) and reader(1)) and this will give you an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. A DataReader process one record at time and the new record is loaded only when you call the Read method.

Comment: Thank you much!!! Yes I forget the reader(1) because I take the cycle from another part of the code.